# Syntax problem with aggregate functions and subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I'm trying to query a 3 table data base Orders, customer and salesperson. 
In order to find more information on the recent peformance of the salesperson. The wanted categories are the id,age, # of orders where amout > 1000, had order where amount > 500 (y/n), Number of unique customers served, days since last order and finally last order amount.

My code is like the following, can also be viewed in link:

```
SELECT  o.salesperson_id
    s.Age,
    (CASE WHEN o.Amount > 500 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS 'Had Order Bigger Than 500?',
    (datediff(day,o.order_date,GETDATE())) AS 'Days Since Last Order',

    o.Amount as 'Last Order Amount'
    FROM Orders o INNER JOIN Salesperson s ON o.salesperson_id = s.ID
      WHERE o.Amount IN
      (SELECT o.Amount WHERE o.order_date = MAX (o.order_date) FROM Orders)

    GROUP BY o.salesperson_id 
    HAVING (COUNT (DISTINCT o.cust_id)) AS 'Number of Unique Customers Served',
    (SUM(CASE WHEN o.Amount > 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Number of Orders Bigger Than 1000'

    ORDER BY o.salesperson_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4fc5c/69

The auto debugger says the problem is with my FROM but I'm dumb founded

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

My expected result would be something like this:

```
+----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| Salesperson ID | Salesperson Age | Number of Orders Bigger Than 1000 | Had Order Bigger Than 500? (y/n)  | Number of Unique Customers Served | Days Since Last Order | Last Order Amount |
+----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|              1 |              61 |                                 0 | N                                 |                                 1 |                       |               460 |
|              2 |              34 |                                 1 | Y                                 |                                 2 |                       |              2400 |
|              8 |              57 |                                 1 | y                                 |                                 1 |                       |              1800 |
+----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

Would extremely appreciate all aid received.

Comment: sqlfiddle is great, but also add sample table data and the expect result here, and the query attempt too. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: `WHERE` comes after `FROM`

Comment: The table in the subquery in the `WHERE` clause needs an alias. That's the `FROM` that is bad.

Comment: What @HoneyBadger says. And your subquery just after "WHERE o.Amount in" refers to the main table alias (o) for your Orders table instead of the copy you use in your subquery

Comment: The query needs to be checked where `"Where"` clause comes after `"From"`  clause. Also you cannot use aggregate functions directly in `"Where"` Clause. For that `"Having"` clause must be used.

Comment: @ChrisBE Well thank you, but I'm not sure I entirely understand - I'm calling the same table to get o.Amount but to make manipulation in it (this case take the amount where the date is latest) so how can I alias it without breaking functionality?

Comment: I have edited code to reflect changes but it seems to still find offence in my from even though now its before the where

Comment: Your code is full of syntactical errors. Edit and explain what you want to do and what is your expected results.

Comment: @forpas Edited to explain more clearly what my query is trying to do, expected result table at bottom now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join Salesperson and Orders, group by salesperson and use conditional aggregation:

```
select
  s.ID [Salesperson ID], 
  s.Age [Salesperson Age],
  sum(case when o.Amount > 1000 then 1 else 0 end) [Number of Orders Bigger Than 1000],
  case when sum(case when o.Amount > 500 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end [Had Order Bigger Than 500? (y/n)],
  count(distinct cust_id) [Number of Unique Customers Served],
  datediff(day, max(o.order_date), GETDATE()) [Days Since Last Order],
  (select Amount from Orders where salesperson_id = s.ID and order_date = max(o.order_date))[Last Order Amount]
from Salesperson s inner join Orders o
on o.salesperson_id = s.ID
group by s.ID, s.Age
order by s.ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7c97321f57360b9bb1d7dbb360671654).
Results:

```
> Salesperson ID | Salesperson Age | Number of Orders Bigger Than 1000 | Had Order Bigger Than 500? (y/n) | Number of Unique Customers Served | Days Since Last Order | Last Order Amount
> -------------: | --------------: | --------------------------------: | :------------------------------- | --------------------------------: | --------------------: | ----------------:
>              1 |              61 |                                 0 | No                               |                                 1 |                  8883 |               460
>              2 |              34 |                                 1 | Yes                              |                                 2 |                  7953 |              2400
>              8 |              57 |                                 1 | Yes                              |                                 1 |                  7587 |              1800
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query `syntax` is entirely wrong. Please try this.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/97188/1)**

```
SELECT  o.salesperson_id, s.Age,
     (SUM(CASE WHEN o.Amount > 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Number of Orders Bigger Than 1000',
     (CASE WHEN o.Amount > 500 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS 'Had Order Bigger Than 500?',
     (COUNT (o.cust_id)) AS 'Number of Unique Customers Served',
     (datediff(day,o.order_date,GETDATE())) AS 'Days Since Last Order',
     o.Amount as 'Last Order Amount'  
FROM Orders o INNER JOIN Salesperson s ON o.salesperson_id = s.ID
WHERE o.Amount IN
( 
  SELECT Amount 
  FROM Orders OO
  WHERE order_date IN (SELECT MAX(order_date) FROM Orders GROUP BY salesperson_id)
)
GROUP BY o.salesperson_id,s.Age,o.Amount, (datediff(day,o.order_date,GETDATE()))
ORDER BY o.salesperson_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! So, to reiterate for learning purposes -  the main errors in my original code are the following: 1. improperly using () for case and aggregate function 2. wrong WHERE and FROM order 3. repetitive and renduant call to amount in subquery. Two things that are still unclear to me- when I need to use HAVING as you clearly didn't here. and secondly, can you not subquery the same table without aliasing it?

Comment: You can have aggregate functions in select clause, if you want use it for where clauses then you may need to use via having clause not in where clauses

Comment: The results for [Number of Unique Customers Served] are wrong.